# Trouble creating symbolic link

Tags: command-line, software-installation, symlink, executable

I installed a software on OpenSUSE. However, to open it one has to type

```
/usr/local/software/start_software
```

everytime.

I tried creating a symbolic link using

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/software/start_software sw_cmd
```

This created an icon 'sw_cmd' in Root which upon double clicking opens the software.
The intention is to create an alias for the path. I am expecting to not have to type the whole every time I want to start the software. I want to create a command sw_cmd should open/start the software.

Comment: Please [edit] and clarify. We don't know what `start_software` is or what it's supposed to be doing. Also, you probably want `/usr/local/software/start_software`, not `usr/local/software/start_software`. What were you expecting the link to do? What do you mean "work like a command for opening the software from terminal"? Are you looking for an alias perhaps? Basically, [edit] your question and explain what exactly you need to do.

Comment: Use _absolute paths_.  Put a `/` before `usr`.

Comment: The title is misleading. You had no problem creating the symlink, but no, a symlink at the root of the filesystem  won't bring your `start_software` in your `$PATH`. Also, `software` directly in `/usr/local` doesn't follow the FHS.

Comment: @terdon I have tried to explain better. start_software is a file in the folder that launches the software. The software opens and works fine when accessed via the longer link. I just wanted to have a one word command to avoid typing the path every time.

Comment: @Leiaz So, what do you suggest I should do?

Comment: As terdon said, you probably want an alias.

Answer (score 1):

In order to invoke a command by name, you need to put that symbolic link in one of the directories on the command search path. The [environment variable `PATH`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29) lists the directories in the command search path. The command in your question creates a symbolic link in the current directory, which is not useful.

For system-wide commands not provided in a package, use the directory `/usr/local/bin`. [`/usr/local`](http://www.linuxbase.org/betaspecs/fhs/fhs/ch04s09.html) in general is for locally-managed software.

```
sudo ln -s ../software/start_software /usr/local/bin/sw_cmd
```

or

```
cd /usr/local/bin
sudo ln -s ../software/start_software sw_cmd
```

Alternatively, you can add an [alias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_%28command%29) for the command in your shell startup file. If you're using bash, put the following command in `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias sw_cmd=/usr/local/software/start_software
```

This is a user-specific setting, so only your account will be able to use the `sw_cmd` alias. Also, this setting is only applicable in interactive shells.